# How are the two intervals equivalent?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, inequality

[image]

How is $0 < z-x < 1$ equivalent to $z-1 < x < z$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$0 < z-x < 1 \iff -z < -x < 1-z \iff z > x> z-1.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}0&<z-x<1\\ 0&>x-z>-1\\ -1&<x-z<0\\ \implies z&-1<x<z\end{align}$$